# how to add a retry advice with jms:message-driven-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to spring integration. My requirement is that if there is a connection problem to the jms q then it should try to connect 3 times then log it and exit the process. I am not able to do it. It throws an error saying it needs the ref attribute for service:activator. But I don't have/know reference of which class to provide here. Is there any other way of doing it?

```html
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="msgIn" channel="toRoute" container="messageListenerContainer" />

<int:service-activator id="service" input-channel="toRoute" >
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
  <property name="recoveryCallback">
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer">
                    <constructor-arg ref=“errorChannel" />
                </bean>
            </property>
   </bean>
    </request-handler-advice-chain>
</int:service-activator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have completely misunderstood what the framework does.

The service-activator gets a message when one is received from JMS (which implies the connection is good), and needs "something" (a reference to a bean or an expression) to invoke as a result of receiving that message.

The retry advice is to retry calling that service if it fails to process the message for some reason. It is unrelated to whatever is the source of the message (JMS in this case).

It's not clear why you are trying to use Spring Integration for something as simple as testing whether a JMS broker is available.

Perhaps if you can provide some larger context someone might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks Gary for putting me in the right context. That surely helps.

Comment: As for the requirement, checking the availability of the broker is just a part. We have a entire application which pulls message from one q and puts to another and so on. This is a small requirement which my mgr wanted me to do. But since I am new to this, kinda out of ideas.

Comment: You can simply call `createConnection()` on your connection factory; if it succeeds you're ok (close it); if not, shut down after some number of attempts (although it's not clear why you would want to do that). With a message listener container, Spring will keep trying to connect indefinitely until successful.

Comment: Thanks Gary. How abut we set these properties like this on the CachingConnectionFactory -- <bean id="remoteConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
<property name="reconnectOnException" value=“true”/>
<property name="exceptionListener" ref=“customExceptionListener"/>
            …….
    </bean> and then provide my own implementation of the customExceptionListener. Do you think I can do like this. ?

Comment: Yes; that should work for you. In future, don't put code/config snippets in comments - they don't render well - it's better to edit your question.